# Prevent title from appearing on mouseover

Tags: jquery, attributes, title

I couldn't find anything that solved my problem in previous posts, so here's my question:

I'm working with a Fancybox image gallery and when I mouse-over the thumbnails on the main page, they're picking up the title from the first big image in each of the the sets that pop up in the lightbox. I don't want that to happen - I don't want anything appearing on mouse-over of the thumbnails.

Is there anyway to keep that from happening?

```
<div class="imglist"> 
<div align="center">
<a class="fancybox" rel="set1" href="images/Arch/OVAL/entry.jpg" 
    title="Richmond Olympic Oval - Entry">
<img src="images/headers/1.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So is this jQuery? Also post your current code.

Comment: Yes, jQuery. Here is the html of one set of images ... I can't seem to hit return to make a line break without posting the comment ... `<div class="imglist">
       <div align="center"><a class="fancybox" rel="set1" href="images/Arch/OVAL/entry.jpg" title="Richmond Olympic Oval - Entry"><img src="images/headers/1.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0"></a></div>`

Comment: The only way by doing that is removing the title attributes. If you can, change a setting in fancybox to read the titles from `data-title` instead of `title`, and change all your `title` attributes to `data-title`, that will prevent the browser from making those tooltips.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the way to go as I want to retain the titles for the images that show in the lightbox. I just don't know where in fancy box to do that. there doesn't seem to be anything in the configurable section of the fancybox js file. Can I do a find/replace in the jquery js file that came with the download?

Comment: There is something on the web site that says this: _title Overrides title content, accepts any HTML String; Default value: null_ ... I just don't know what that means!

Comment: I fixed it! I found three instances of attr('title' in the js, changed them to attr('data-title' and now I get the titles on the images in the lightbox, but nothing on the hover over the thumbnails. It seems to work on all browsers too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way to style (or hide) the default `title` attribute using CSS.
One way of going about it in jQuery is to remove it on hover:

```
$('[title]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('title', $this.attr('title')).prop('title', null);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('title', $this.data('title')).data('title', null);
});
```

---

Or you can remove it permanently

```
(function($) {
    $('.i-dont-want-title').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title')).prop('title', null);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And use it for custom tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I found three instances of attr('title' in the js, changed them to attr('data-title' and now I get the titles on the images in the lightbox, but nothing on the hover over the thumbnails. It seems to work on all browsers too.

Thanks for the suggestion, Thew.